# request.FILES in Django empty when file transfered through create() in Backbone

Tags: javascript, django, backbone.js, file-upload, request

Each `todo model` can have a file attached `FileUpload` attribute.

`todo model` attributes:

1. `title`
2. `FileUpload`

But when creating a `todo model` through `collection.create()`, the attached file is not able to be accessed through `request.FILES` in django

**main.js**: (instantiating a `todo model` and creating it through `collection.create` )

```
filePDF = $('input[name="pdfUpload"]')[0].files[0]; 
var todo = new Todo({title:this.$('#new_todo').val().trim(),FileUpload:filePDF})
this.collection.create(todo);
```

**NOTES**: posting here a part of the main.js as I am positively sure, it is the `create()` part that is creating issues. But if more clarity is needed, do let me know.

**views.py**

```
class TaskMixin(object,):
    serializer_class = TaskSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsOwnerOrReadOnly,)
    def get_queryset(self):
        if(not self.request.user.is_staff):
            return Task.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
        else:
            return Task.objects.all()

class TaskList(TaskMixin, ListCreateAPIView):
    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)
    pass
```

**Question:** How should the uploaded file be sent across to django, so that it can be accessed through `request.FILES` ?